# playonlinux depends x-terminal-emulator but it is a virtual package

Tags: software-installation, playonlinux

I am having a `depends x-terminal-emulator but it is a virtual package` error whe I try installing playonlinux via the doftware center. See screenshot below:

[image]

Any solutions?

Comment: This is Ubuntu 12.04, right?

Comment: Yes it is 12.04 LTS